The Fn button on the keyboard does not work
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and the Fn button on my Nuphy keyboard no longer works. I can't use the F1, F2, etc. buttons. Only the volume up, down, mute, etc. keys work (that is, they work by default and you can't switch). On a Redmi laptop, the native keyboard works as it should, all the keys work as they should (Fn for multimedia works, F1, F2, etc. work). Please tell me how to solve this problem?
